# Registry value each time it runs

Tags: powershell

I started creating this script and I got stuck at one thing that I want to accomplish. This script runs fine. But what I really want to do is when this script is run more than once, I want to change the value to the number of times this script was use. How do I accomplish this?

```
$RegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\"
$NewRegKey = "SCCM"
$NewRegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM"
$KeyName = "Attempts" 
$Value = "1"
New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Name $NewRegKey -Force 
New-ItemProperty -Path $NewRegKeyPath -Name $KeyName -Value $Value -PropertyType DWORD -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
```

NEW script:
(Working)

```
#This is creating the SCCM Hive and add the key W10_IPU_Attempts
If (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

} Else {
$RegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\"
$NewRegKey = "SCCM"
New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Name $NewRegKey -Force 
$NewRegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM"
$KeyName = "W10_IPU_Attempts"
$Value = "0"
New-ItemProperty -Path $NewRegKeyPath -Name $KeyName -Value $Value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null

}

#Set value in increment of 1 each time this script is ran!
$i= 
$Value =(Get-Itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM').W10_IPU_Attempts

If ($i -eq $value){

$i++
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i 
}
else {
$i++
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i
}
```

Comment: Have you runned this script without `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and got some error? If yes, which was it?

Comment: With or without it it runs fine. What I am really after is how it adds the value to the number of times this script is run. Any idea?

Comment: You must retrieve the "Attempts" value (with `Get-ItemProperty` command, for example) and increase its value.

Comment: Manually? I know i can change it. But how about the registry updates the value by itself when the script is run?

Comment: @DudebePSing - the registry WILL NOT update itself. [*grin*] you need to add code to your script to read the value, increment it, and then write it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) with your bunch of parameters.

Otherwise do as suggested, (check) read current value set incremented value,
if not present, create the key

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\17\SO_56190969.ps1
$RegistryPath  = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\"
$NewRegKey     = "SCCM"
$NewRegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM"
$KeyName       = "Attempts"

if ($Value=[Int](Get-ItemPropertyValue $NewRegKeyPath -Name $KeyName -EA 0)){
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $NewRegKeyPath -Name $KeyName -Value (++$Value) -Type DWord
} else {
    New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Name $NewRegKey -Force | Out-Null
    $params = @{
        Path        = $NewRegKeyPath
        Name        = $KeyName
        Value       = 1
        PropertyType= 'DWORD'
        Force       = $True
        ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
    New-ItemProperty @params | Out-Null
}

"Key    : {0}`nKeyname: {1}`nValue  : {2}" -f $NewRegKeyPath,$KeyName,
    (Get-ItemPropertyValue $NewRegKeyPath -Name $KeyName)
#
```

Two sample runs:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\17\SO_56190969.ps1
Key    : HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM
Keyname: Attempts
Value  : 1

> Q:\Test\2019\05\17\SO_56190969.ps1
Key    : HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM
Keyname: Attempts
Value  : 2
```

Comment: Thanks. Yours works as well. I edited my original post and added what I created and seems to be working as expected.

Comment: can you help me put this into a one liner? I was thinking it will make it easier for me to apply this to a Task Sequence. Thank you in advance.